# Create a custom article template in Joomla! 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

So right now I'm managing a staff of about 30 people working on a school website based off of Joomla 1.5.  I am trying to make all of our Joomla articles regarding our sports teams follow the same general template ([example](http://pvphs.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=768&Itemid=81)).  Right now, I'm just having everyone do it individually, which obviously causes quite a few inconsistencies.  Ideally I would like to replace the articles in that section with a form (on the backend) that just has input fields for the various information (team name, schedule, roster, coaches, etc.) and then displays it using the template on the frontend.  The closet thing I have found is [Content Templater](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/contenttemplater), but I'm wondering if there is a better way.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using joomla's core article system you can try using a very popular joomla extension K2 http://getk2.org/

It had all the features that are available in joomla content system. In addition to it you can create custom field.

As in your case just create a category sports team, create an extra fields group with files like team name, schedule, roster, coaches   and select this field group while creating a category.

Now all the items in that category will show these custom fields where you can enter your data.

It also provide a great template system so that you can create different layouts for different category . See here http://getk2.org/documentation/tutorials/item/174-templating-with-k2-and-the-concepts-of-sub-templates